# Images and page performance HTML

Tags: javascript, performance, dom

I am currently working on a javascript that removes the src links before they are added to the dom, so no http requests are made, and then I reset the links when the user is at a scrolling proximity of the image, I do this to improve the performance of my pages.

But I was wondering, since I am only "hiding" the upcoming  not visible images, would it be useful if I also hid the previous images?

what I mean by that is remove the images Src of the images above the window, and beneath it, instead of just beneath.

is there a performance improvement by doing so?
or should I just keep the previous images and don't touch em.

**TL;DR**
Does hiding images that are already loaded in the dom improve performance?

Comment: Yes and no; if you have tens of thousands of different images then you may get worse performance than if they're all pointing to the same dummy place, but otherwise, you have already loaded them - they're doing little harm. I'm more interested in seeing how you remove a _src_ from the _HTML_ before it's added (assuming you've not simply shadowed `appendChild` and `insertBefore`)

Comment: Why are you bothering to do this magic with removing `src`? Add `display: none` style to all images and the result is the same. Browsers are smart these days, they won't load such images.

Comment: Paul.S is there a way to remove them from the browser cache then? so when the user is at their proximity, I just reply the src for another request.

matewka, css is slow for handling this kind of thing, also i am planning to do other things in the process.

PaulS. if you are interested, I am currently using angularJs linking
so before the dom is altered inside a directive, I handle the src.
Inspired by : http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2498-Lazy-Loading-Image-With-AngularJS.htm